# Does caret::train() in r have a standardized output across different fit methods/models?

Tags: r, regression, r-caret, data-fitting

I'm working with the `train()` function from the caret package to fit multiple regression and ML models to test their fit. I'd like to write a function that iterates through all model types and enters the best fit into a dataframe. Biggest issue is that caret doesn't provide all the model fit statistics that I'd like so they need to be derived from the raw output. Based on my exploration there doesn't seem to be a standardized way caret outputs each models fit.

Another post (sorry don't have a link) created this function which pulls from `fit$results` and `fit$bestTune` to get pre calculated RMSE, R^2, etc.

```
get_best_result <- function(caret_fit) {
   best = which(rownames(caret_fit$results) == rownames(caret_fit$bestTune))
   best_result = caret_fit$results[best, ]
   rownames(best_result) = NULL
   best_result
}
```

One example of another fit statistic I need to calculate using raw output is BIC. The two functions below do that. The residuals (y_actual - y_predicted) are needed along with the number of x variables (k) and the number of rows used in the prediction (n). k and n must be derived from the output not the original dataset due to the models dropping x variables (feature selection) or rows (omitting NAs) based on its algorithm.

```
calculate_MSE <- function(residuals){
   # residuals can be replaced with y_actual-y_predicted
   mse <- mean(residuals^2)
   return(mse)
}

calculate_BIC <- function(n, mse, k){
   BIC <- n*log(mse)+k*log(n)
   return(BIC)
}
```

**The real question is** is there a standardized output of `caret::train()` for x variables or either y_actual, y_predicted, or residuals?

I tried `fit$finalModel$model` and other methods but to no avail.

Here is a reproducible example along with the function I'm using. Please consider the functions above a part of this reproducible example.

```
library(rlist)
library(data.table)

# data
df <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(50, 0, 1),
                  y2 = rnorm(50, .25, 1.5),
                  x1 = rnorm(50, .4, .9),
                  x2 = rnorm(50, 0, 1.1),
                  x3 = rnorm(50, 1, .75))
missing_index <- sample(1:50, 7, replace = F)
df[missing_index,] <- NA

# function to fit models and pull results
fitModels <- function(df, Ys, Xs, models){
   # empty list
   results <- list()
   # number of for loops
   loops_counter <- 0
   # for every y
   for(y in 1:length(Ys)){
     # for every model
     for(m in 1:length(models)){
       # track loops
       loops_counter <- loops_counter + 1
       # fit the model
       set.seed(1) # seed for reproducability
       fit <- tryCatch(train(as.formula(paste(Ys[y], paste(Xs, collapse = ' + '),
                                              sep = ' ~ ')),
                             data = df,
                             method = models[m],
                             na.action = na.omit,
                             tuneLength = 10),
       error = function(e) {return(NA)})

       # pull results
       results[[loops_counter]] <- c(Y = Ys[y],
                                     model = models[m],
                                     sample_size = nrow(fit$finalModel$model),
                                     RMSE = get_best_result(fit)[[2]],
                                     R2 = get_best_result(fit)[[3]],
                                     MAE = get_best_result(fit)[[4]],
                                     BIC = calculate_BIC(n = length(fit$finalModel),
                                                         mse = calculate_MSE(fit$finalModel$residuals),
                                                         k = length(fit$finalModel$xNames)))
      }
   }
   # list bind
   results_df <- list.rbind(results)
   return(results_df)
}

linear_models <- c('lm', 'glmnet', 'ridge',  'lars', 'enet')

fits <- fitModels(df, c(y1, y2), c(x1,x2,x3), linear_models)
```

Comment: `fit$finalModel` is algorithm specific and very few methods will have a unified structure. Getting RMSE, MAE, R2 and similar metrics for the train data is of very limited interest because the more flexible algorithm you use the better it will fit on the training data. This unfortunately doses not correlate good with generalizing power (prediction on unseen data). However calculating the metrics on out of fold (testing data) is of interest, caret has in built functions for this.

Comment: @missuse thank you for your comment. What is the test function for predicting the test set? Can't `train()` do this all together? Either way, do you know the syntax to extract the ~useful~ test statistics?

Comment: To test the performance of your model you can simply use `predict(caret_model,test_data)` and use the output in one of the summary function like `defaultSummary` or `RMSE`. Have a look [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/defaultSummary) fot those functions

Comment: @kentkr in [`trainControl`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/trainControl) set `savePredictions = TRUE` and for each observation in each resampling instance you fill have actual and predicted values in the resulting `train` object which can be used to calculate any metric you whish.